# Openstack Liberty router, firewall panels not shown in Horizon

Tags: openstack-horizon, openstack-neutron

I've just deployed Liberty on a single machine using the [official doc](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/).

For neutron, I used [Provider networks](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/neutron-controller-install-option1.html) configuration.

When accessing horizon dashboard, I found that the router tab was missing.

Is this a common issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the horizon config file local_settings.py, make sure enable_router is set to True.

```
OPENSTACK_NEUTRON_NETWORK = {
    ...
    'enable_router': True,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I 've already fixed it with this config. I Thought that I've shared the sol but I did not. My bad ! Thank you @Q.Tian